# Making a percentage of JUnit tests pass

Tags: java, junit

Is there an easy way to tell JUnit that you only want a certain percentage or number of tests to pass?  I'm mainly looking for something at the method level but class level is fine too.

I understand this is unconventional for unit tests but I mostly work on machine learning where I don't expect every single test to pass.

Comment: Instead of asking a single test to pass some of the time, you could make the method which exercises your code repeatedly, gathers statistics, and only declares a "pass" if the success rate is above a minimum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend writing a custom @Rule.  You could start with the ErrorCollector implementation and modify it to not report errors under a certain percentage.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep track of the number of all tests already passed in an `int` and always update it and check whether it's above a certain threshold in an @After method (which is run after each test).

Comment: Good point, I already do something like that but I didn't think about using @After to validate, thanks!